# Log4j2 backward compatibility problems

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to migrate from log4j to log4j2. The configurations are in place and even logging is working properly as per my configurations. But it only works when I use the following imports and configurators.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
.
.
Configurator.initialize(null, pathToConfigFile);
.
.
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MetricsTopic.class);
```

However, my older import is still a valid import but doesn't seem to load the configuration properly. 
here are the older imports (which do not work):

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MetricsTopic.class);
```

can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Log4j 2's log4j-1.2-api jar? You should not have the log4j 1 jar present.